# .net Windows service on windows server 2012 R2 read from excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a .net windows service built to read from excel and write on excel sheet ,, i have installed it on windows server 2012 R2 and received this error message,although full permission have been set to the folder :

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file . There are several possible reasons:
• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: Make sure you have a regular Excel user set up on the [service's Log On tab](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current service and use below steps -

go to start > All Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio> Visual Studio Tools

> right click on "Developer Command Prompt for vs(version)" > go to "Run as Administrator"

Enter the command to install your service.

installutil.exe E:\Projects\MyNewService\MyTestService.exe